# How can i delete with powershell all sites from a sitecollection without the rootweb?

Tags: powershell

How can i delete with powershell all sites from  a sitecollection without the rootweb?

I found this:

```
Get-SPSite <SiteUrl> | Get-SPWeb -Limit All | ForEach-Object {Remove-SPWeb -Identity $_ -Confirm:$false}
```

but it iterates over all webs, which means it will iterate over the root web and I dont want to delete the rootweb

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one, changing the url to the url of your Rootweb

```
$url = "http://portal.com"
$subsites = ((Get-SPWeb $url).Site).allwebs | ?{$_.url -like $url +"/*"}

foreach($subsite in $subsites) { Remove-SPWeb $subsite.url }
```

Comment: Cannot find an SPSite object with Id or Url: http://xxxxxm/sites/10003160/86100077Z23 Its weird because the subweb exists!

Comment: lol I had to do remove-spweb instead of sp-site

Comment: Sorry about that, now updated

Answer (score 3):

```
($s = Get-SPSite <SiteUrl>) | Get-SPWeb -Limit All | Where-Object {$_.Id -ne $s.RootWeb.Id} | ForEach-Object {Remove-SPWeb -Identity $_ -Confirm:$false}
```